# Multiple conditions on the joined table when using group by

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have two tables:

**products**

```
id    name
1     Product 1
2     Product 2
3     Product 3
```

**products_sizes**

```
id    size_id    product_id
1     1          1
2     2          1
3     1          2
4     3          2
5     3          3
```

So product 1 has two sizes: 1, 2. Product 2 has two sizes: 1, 3. Product 3 has one size: 3.

What I want to do is build a query that pulls back the products that have both size 1 and size 3 (i.e. Product 2). I can easily create a query that pulls back the products that have **both** sizes 1 AND 3:

```
select `products`.id, `products_sizes`.`size_id`
from `products` inner join `products_sizes` on `products`.`id` = `products_sizes`.`product_id`
where products_sizes.size_id IN (1, 3)
group by products.id
```

When I run this query, I get back Product 1, Product 2, and Product 3.

Just to reiterate, I'd like to only get back Product 2. I've tried using the HAVING clause, messing around with $id IN GROUP_CONCAT(...) but I haven't been able to get anything to work. Thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: What is your output should be look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want both 1 and 3, you need to `COUNT` the `size_id`s that are `IN (1, 3)` and require the result to be 2:

```
SELECT p.id AS id, p.name AS name
FROM   products p, products_sizes s
WHERE  p.id = s.product_id AND s.size_id IN (1, 3)
GROUP  BY s.product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.size_id) = 2;
```

Check out the [**demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be28a/8). Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of simple solution I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This one might work for you in MySQL, if group_concat works the same way it does in PostgreSQL:

```
select 
  product_id 
from products
left join ( select group_concat(cast(id as char(5)), ',') as agg1 from sz where id in (1, 3) group by size_id ) as qagg1 on 1=1
left join ( select products_sizes.product_id product_id, group_concat(cast(products_sizes.size_id as char(5)), ',') agg2 from sz where products_sizes.size_id IN (1, 3) group by products_sizes.product_id ) as qagg2 on 1=1
where qagg1.agg1 = qagg2.agg2
group by product_id
```

This is the original query, tested in PostgreSQL:

```
select 
  product_id 
from pr
left join ( select string_agg(cast(id as char(5)), ',') as agg1 from sz where id in (1, 3) group by size_id ) as qagg1 on 1=1
left join ( select sz.product_id product_id, string_agg(cast(sz.size_id as char(5)), ',') agg2 from sz where sz.size_id IN (1, 3) group by sz.product_id ) as qagg2 on 1=1
where qagg1.agg1 = qagg2.agg2
group by product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Talking about performance, it would be a nice deal to filter to a certain size_id first:

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
x.id, y.size_id AS size_1, z.size_id AS size_2
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM products_sizes
  WHERE size_id = 1
) AS y
INNER JOIN products AS x
  ON (x.id = y.product_id)
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM products_sizes
  WHERE size_id = 3
) AS z
ON (x.id = z.product_id);
```

Humble suggestion, make some tests with a higher amount of data (:

Answer (score 0):

```
select `products`.id, `products_sizes`.`size_id`
from `products` inner join `products_sizes` on `products`.`id` = `products_sizes`.`product_id`
where products_sizes.size_id IN (1, 3)
group by products.id
having count(distinct `products_sizes`.size_id) = 2;
```